# how to en-queue jQuery to load before the </body> tag

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I've enqueued all my scripts on function.php to load before the  tag by passing 'true' to the fifth argument. It does works for all of them BUT jquery, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery','','','',true);
wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('my-javascript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-javascript.js', array('jquery', 'modernizr'), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
```

Comment: Would also like an answer to that. Have the same code for jQuery but it still loads after the `head`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to functions.php

```
<?php

// Custom scripting to move JavaScript from the head to the footer
function remove_head_scripts()
{
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);

    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_head_scripts');

?>
```